# Connection Character Sets and Collations

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

estoy leyendo el manuel de MYSQL, en el punto "10.4 Connection Character Sets and Collations" pone esto:

> SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_%';
> SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'collation_%';
>
> Clients can fine-tune the settings for these variables, or depend on the defaults (in which case, you can skip the rest of this section). If you do not use the defaults, you must change the character settings for each connection to the server.

Yo tengo varias BBDD con utf8mb4 y de COLLATION utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
Como se ve no es la default para utf8mb4 la cual es utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci. ¿ Debería ajustar la variable character_set_client o character_set_connection? .

Tampoco consigo ver en el workbrench que character usa para la conexion con MYSQL. He mirado en "edit connection" y no veo esta información.